# Sendmail not forwarding mail for domains in /etc/mail/local-domain-hosts

Tags: smtp, sendmail, amazon-ami

First off, I have been using sendmail for about a week, and have a semi-working instance. This issue very well may be something simple/overlooked.

I have an AMI server that is running sendmail and dovecot. it is also the destination for a few email addresses at `example.com`. I have an external application that sends the mail as a user on this machine by connecting as a local user. I can define the FROM address to anything, fictional or otherwise.

If I have the domain `example.com` in `/etc/mail/local-host-names`, I can receive mail sent TO `example.com` to my local Maildir without getting the following error (loopback issue):

```
553 5.3.5 example.com. config error: mail loops back to me (MX problem?)
```

If I send a mail to be relayed with a FROM address @example.com, it does not get relayed, and is lost to the ether.

If I remove `example.com` from `/etc/mail/local-host-names`, I cannot receive mail to `example.com` (see error above), but I **can** relay mail that is being sent from my external application using domain `example.com`.

In a nutshell,  I can either relay with a FROM @example.com with the `etc/mail/local-host-names` empty, or I can receive with a TO @example.com with the `etc/mail/local-host-names` populated. But I cannot receive AND send with either config.

What gives?

Comment: I'm getting confused.  Where does the mailbox for example.com reside.  Where do you want emails for example.com to go?

Comment: Hey Mike. I have mailboxes for example.com all on the server. I want to receive email to these boxes to be fetched by IMAP later. 

I want emails TO example.com to be delivered here. I want emails sent FROM example.com to be sent out beyond this server, which is not happening.